# How to exclude record in elastic Search in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch

I have to use the elastic search for the show the document.
I have written a query like below.

```
 var result = elastic.Search<DocPosts>(s => s.Index(indexname).AllTypes().From(data.from).Size(data.PageSize).Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Should(sh =>
                sh.Match(mt1 => mt1.OnField(f => f.Text).Query(SQuery)) ||
                sh.Match(mt2 => mt2.OnField(f => f.Title).Query(SQuery))

                ))).Highlight(h => h
                    .OnFields(f => f.OnField(d => d.DocText).PreTags("<mark>").PostTags("</mark>"), f => f.OnField(d => d.Title).PreTags("<mark>").PostTags("</mark>"))
                        ).Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Id, Id)));
```

this is working perfectly.

in this, I want to exclude some record that has come in below query.

```
var Proc = (from p in db.Pro where p.ParId == ParId && (u.UserId != temp.UserId || u.UserId == null)
                                select p.procID).ToList();
```

how can I perform this filter or exclude from elastic search?

Comment: You can use must not within a bool..where you can mention the clauses to be excluded

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html

you can an find the details in above link

Comment: please provide the c# solution.